# Add Column Dynamically in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to add column dynamically

i have syntax like this

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,ID_KILN VARCHAR(4))
    WHILE @I <= @JML_NO
        BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TABLE ADD NoUrut_@I varchar(20)
            SET @I = @I + 1
        END
```

Comment: There are many examples of how to write and execute dynamic TSQL in SQL Server (which you could easily find by searching for it). What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic command and execute it using `EXEC(...)`

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,ID_KILN VARCHAR(4))

DECLARE
  @I int=1,
  @JML_NO int=10,
  @cmd varchar(100)

WHILE @I <= @JML_NO
BEGIN
    SET @cmd=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TABLE ADD NoUrut_',@I,' varchar(20)')

    EXEC(@cmd)

    SET @I += 1
END

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP_TABLE

DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
```